# Bleed through using TableHeadFixer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using TableHeadFixer at https://github.com/lai32290/TableHeadFixer to create a table with a Fixed header. It seems to do what I need and is fairly lightweight. But I'm having one problem I can't seem to fix. The contents of the table bleed through the top of the fixed header when scrolling. My code:

```
$(function() {
  $('table').tableHeadFixer();
});
```

jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/peterkronenberg/n5uzoLcw/

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If looks like a bug in that specific plugin, but you can solve it using `margin-top: -2px` on the `<table>` element:

```js
$(function() {
    $('table').tableHeadFixer();

});



(function ($) {

    $.fn.tableHeadFixer = function (param) {

        return this.each(function () {
            table.call(this);
        });

        function table() {

            {
                var defaults = {
                    head: true,
                    foot: false,
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    'z-index': 0
                };

                var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, param);

                settings.table  = this;
                settings.parent = $(settings.table).parent();
                setParent();

                if (settings.head == true)
                    fixHead();

                if (settings.foot == true)
                    fixFoot();

                if (settings.left > 0)
                    fixLeft();

                if (settings.right > 0)
                    fixRight();

                setCorner();

                $(settings.parent).trigger("scroll");

                $(window).resize(function () {
                    $(settings.parent).trigger("scroll");
                });


                /*
                 This function solver z-index problem in corner cell where fix row and column at the same time,
                 set corner cells z-index 1 more then other fixed cells
                 */
                function setCorner() {
                    var table = $(settings.table);

                    if (settings.head) {
                        if (settings.left > 0) {
                            var tr = table.find("thead tr");

                            tr.each(function (k, row) {
                                solverLeftColspan(row, function (cell) {
                                    $(cell).css("z-index", settings['z-index'] + 1);
                                });
                            });
                        }

                        if (settings.right > 0) {
                            var tr = table.find("thead tr");

                            tr.each(function (k, row) {
                                solveRightColspan(row, function (cell) {
                                    $(cell).css("z-index", settings['z-index'] + 1);
                                });
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    if (settings.foot) {
                        if (settings.left > 0) {
                            var tr = table.find("tfoot tr");

                            tr.each(function (k, row) {
                                solverLeftColspan(row, function (cell) {
                                    $(cell).css("z-index", settings['z-index']);
                                });
                            });
                        }

                        if (settings.right > 0) {
                            var tr = table.find("tfoot tr");

                            tr.each(function (k, row) {
                                solveRightColspan(row, function (cell) {
                                    $(cell).css("z-index", settings['z-index']);
                                });
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Set style of table parent
                function setParent() {
                    var parent = $(settings.parent);
                    var table  = $(settings.table);

                    parent.append(table);
                    parent
                        .css({
                            'overflow-x': 'auto',
                            'overflow-y': 'auto'
                        });

                    parent.scroll(function () {
                        var scrollWidth  = parent[0].scrollWidth;
                        var clientWidth  = parent[0].clientWidth;
                        var scrollHeight = parent[0].scrollHeight;
                        var clientHeight = parent[0].clientHeight;
                        var top          = parent.scrollTop();
                        var left         = parent.scrollLeft();

                        if (settings.head)
                            this.find("thead tr > *").css("top", top);

                        if (settings.foot)
                            this.find("tfoot tr > *").css("bottom", scrollHeight - clientHeight - top);

                        if (settings.left > 0)
                            settings.leftColumns.css("left", left);

                        if (settings.right > 0)
                            settings.rightColumns.css("right", scrollWidth - clientWidth - left);
                    }.bind(table));
                }

                // Set table head fixed
                function fixHead() {
                    var thead = $(settings.table).find("thead");
                    var tr    = thead.find("tr");
                    var cells = thead.find("tr > *");

                    setBackground(cells);
                    cells.css({
                        'position': 'relative'
                    });
                }

                // Set table foot fixed
                function fixFoot() {
                    var tfoot = $(settings.table).find("tfoot");
                    var tr    = tfoot.find("tr");
                    var cells = tfoot.find("tr > *");

                    setBackground(cells);
                    cells.css({
                        'position': 'relative'
                    });
                }

                // Set table left column fixed
                function fixLeft() {
                    var table = $(settings.table);

                    // var fixColumn = settings.left;

                    settings.leftColumns = $();

                    var tr = table.find("tr");
                    tr.each(function (k, row) {

                        solverLeftColspan(row, function (cell) {
                            settings.leftColumns = settings.leftColumns.add(cell);
                        });
                        // var inc = 1;

                        // for(var i = 1; i <= fixColumn; i = i + inc) {
                        //  var nth = inc > 1 ? i - 1 : i;

                        //  var cell = $(row).find("*:nth-child(" + nth + ")");
                        //  var colspan = cell.prop("colspan");

                        //  settings.leftColumns = settings.leftColumns.add(cell);

                        //  inc = colspan;
                        // }
                    });

                    var column = settings.leftColumns;

                    column.each(function (k, cell) {
                        var cell = $(cell);

                        setBackground(cell);
                        cell.css({
                            'position': 'relative'
                        });
                    });
                }

                // Set table right column fixed
                function fixRight() {
                    var table = $(settings.table);

                    var fixColumn = settings.right;

                    settings.rightColumns = $();

                    var tr = table.find("tr");
                    tr.each(function (k, row) {
                        solveRightColspan(row, function (cell) {
                            settings.rightColumns = settings.rightColumns.add(cell);
                        });
                    });

                    var column = settings.rightColumns;

                    column.each(function (k, cell) {
                        var cell = $(cell);

                        setBackground(cell);
                        cell.css({
                            'position': 'relative'
                        });
                    });

                }

                // Set fixed cells backgrounds
                function setBackground(elements) {
                    elements.each(function (k, element) {
                        var element = $(element);
                        var parent  = $(element).parent();

                        var elementBackground = element.css("background-color");
                        elementBackground     = (elementBackground == "transparent" || elementBackground == "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)") ? null : elementBackground;

                        var parentBackground = parent.css("background-color");
                        parentBackground     = (parentBackground == "transparent" || parentBackground == "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)") ? null : parentBackground;

                        var background = parentBackground ? parentBackground : "white";
                        background     = elementBackground ? elementBackground : background;

                        element.css("background-color", background);
                    });
                }

                function solverLeftColspan(row, action) {
                    var fixColumn = settings.left;
                    var inc       = 1;

                    for (var i = 1; i <= fixColumn; i = i + inc) {
                        var nth = inc > 1 ? i - 1 : i;

                        var cell    = $(row).find("> *:nth-child(" + nth + ")");
                        var colspan = cell.prop("colspan");

                        if (cell.cellPos().left < fixColumn) {
                            action(cell);
                        }

                        inc = colspan;
                    }
                }

                function solveRightColspan(row, action) {
                    var fixColumn = settings.right;
                    var inc       = 1;

                    for (var i = 1; i <= fixColumn; i = i + inc) {
                        var nth = inc > 1 ? i - 1 : i;

                        var cell    = $(row).find("> *:nth-last-child(" + nth + ")");
                        var colspan = cell.prop("colspan");

                        action(cell);

                        inc = colspan;
                    }
                }
            }

        }




    };

})(jQuery);

/*  cellPos jQuery plugin
 ---------------------
 Get visual position of cell in HTML table (or its block like thead).
 Return value is object with "top" and "left" properties set to row and column index of top-left cell corner.
 Example of use:
 $("#myTable tbody td").each(function(){
 $(this).text( $(this).cellPos().top +", "+ $(this).cellPos().left );
 });
 */
(function ($) {
    /* scan individual table and set "cellPos" data in the form { left: x-coord, top: y-coord } */
    function scanTable($table) {
        var m = [];
        $table.children("tr").each(function (y, row) {
            $(row).children("td, th").each(function (x, cell) {
                var $cell = $(cell),
                    cspan = $cell.attr("colspan") | 0,
                    rspan = $cell.attr("rowspan") | 0,
                    tx, ty;
                cspan     = cspan ? cspan : 1;
                rspan     = rspan ? rspan : 1;
                for (; m[y] && m[y][x]; ++x);  //skip already occupied cells in current row
                for (tx = x; tx < x + cspan; ++tx) {  //mark matrix elements occupied by current cell with true
                    for (ty = y; ty < y + rspan; ++ty) {
                        if (!m[ty]) {  //fill missing rows
                            m[ty] = [];
                        }
                        m[ty][tx] = true;
                    }
                }
                var pos = {top: y, left: x};
                $cell.data("cellPos", pos);
            });
        });
    };

    /* plugin */
    $.fn.cellPos = function (rescan) {
        var $cell = this.first(),
            pos   = $cell.data("cellPos");
        if (!pos || rescan) {
            var $table = $cell.closest("table, thead, tbody, tfoot");
            scanTable($table);
        }
        pos = $cell.data("cellPos");
        return pos;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  background: #f3f5f6;
}
table {
    margin-top: -2px;
}
table td {
    border: 1px solid black
}

div {
    margin: 10px 20px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table style='height: 300px; width: 400px; padding-top: 0'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Head1</th>
        <th>Head2</th>
        <th>Head3</th>
        <th>Head4</th>
        <th>Head5</th>
        <th>Head6</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>data11</td>
        <td>data12</td>
        <td>data13</td>
        <td>data14</td>
        <td>data15</td>
        <td>data16</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data21</td>
        <td>data22</td>
        <td>data23</td>
        <td>data24</td>
        <td>data25</td>
        <td>data26</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data31</td>
        <td>data32</td>
        <td>data33</td>
        <td>data34</td>
        <td>data35</td>
        <td>data36</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data41</td>
        <td>data42</td>
        <td>data43</td>
        <td>data44</td>
        <td>data45</td>
        <td>data46</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data51</td>
        <td>data52</td>
        <td>data53</td>
        <td>data54</td>
        <td>data55</td>
        <td>data56</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data61</td>
        <td>data62</td>
        <td>data63</td>
        <td>data64</td>
        <td>data65</td>
        <td>data66</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data71</td>
        <td>data72</td>
        <td>data73</td>
        <td>data74</td>
        <td>data75</td>
        <td>data76</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data81</td>
        <td>data82</td>
        <td>data83</td>
        <td>data84</td>
        <td>data85</td>
        <td>data86</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
     <tr>
        <th>Foot1</th>
        <th>Foot2</th>
        <th>Foot3</th>
        <th>Foot4</th>
        <th>Foot5</th>
        <th>Foot6</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  That definitely fixes it in this particular case, but I discovered the more general problem is if you have anything in the div prior to the table.  I updated the jsfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/peterkronenberg/n5uzoLcw/.  Is there a more generalized solution, or is the plugin just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved that bug and couple of others in my fork of that plugin:
https://github.com/DrankUser/TableFixer

You can use it just like the old plugin:

```
$('table').tableFixer({
  left: 1,
  right: 1,
  head: true,
  foot: true,
  z-index: 999,
});
```

Full changelog you can see in readme and commit messages

P.S. I'll try to make a pull request to original plugin repo, but intill that moment you can use mine